# Trying to get sql parameters to work

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

I am trying to build this site to use sql params. I thought I had followed the example I was given, but my sql data shows '@username' and 'number' instead of the values that have been put into the text boxes.

I'm stumped.

thanks for the help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class management_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public void runsql(string sqlCmdTxt, bool adduserbool)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=DELLXPS\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Warren_SEINDATASYSTEMS; Integrated Security=true;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.CommandText = sqlCmdTxt;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;

        //If statement uses adduserbool param to determine if the code needs to make sql params for users
        if (adduserbool == true)
        {
            SqlParameter user = new SqlParameter();
            user.ParameterName = "@username";
            user.Value = CreateUserWizard1.UserName.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(user);

            if (txtboxNumberOfVisitors.Text != "")
            {
                SqlParameter number = new SqlParameter();
                number.ParameterName = "@number";
                number.Value = txtboxNumberOfVisitors.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(number);
            }
            else
            {
                // this else will send "2" if the text box is empty
                SqlParameter number = new SqlParameter();
                number.ParameterName = "@number";
                number.Value = "2";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(number);
            }
        }

        sqlConnection.Open();

        //cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        sqlConnection.Close();

        //if user was created, clear number of visitors text box
        if (adduserbool == true)
        {
            txtboxNumberOfVisitors.Text = "";
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add residents to resident role
            Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, "resident");
            runsql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[NumberOfVisitors] ([ResidentName],[NumberOfVisitors]) VALUES ('@username','@number')", true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you put quotes around the parameter names in your SQL INSERT statement. So SQL thinks it's a literal string, not a reference to a parameter.

Try this:

```
runsql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[NumberOfVisitors] ([ResidentName],[NumberOfVisitors]) VALUES (@username,@number)", true);
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I did that. I figured my problem was in code and didn't even look at my string. Thank you

Comment: Just to be fair it was pushing 6 a.m. and I have been working all night

Answer (score 1):

You have to omit the `'` in your sql statement, because it is not a string, but a parameter:

```
runsql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[NumberOfVisitors] ([ResidentName],[NumberOfVisitors]) VALUES (@username,@number)", true);
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I did that. I figured my problem was in code and didn't even look at my string. Thank you

Comment: Just to be fair it was pushing 6 a.m. and I have been working all night